# Resizing To A Maximum MB

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a website that hosts images of mine for sale and they limit the file size to 25MB per image.

Is there away to have Photoshop resize an image to 25MB. I know how to resize by long side or short side lengths but if it can be done by limiting to 25MB this would be a major time saver and not having to do some trial and error resizing sometimes.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Could you perhaps [edit your quesion](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/121281/edit) to add some more details concerning the images. What format are the images? What size are they in pixels? What is the file size of the original images? What kind of images are they? Drawings, paintings, photographs?

Answer (score 1):

When you use **File** > **Export** > **Export As** or **(Ctrl + Shift + Alt + W)** there is a section that previews the file size before it is exported, see circled image below. As far as I'm aware, there's no way to set the file size as the constraint when exporting in Photoshop
[image]